# How to edit a FabricJS IText and apply new styles (e.g. highlighting, etc...)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to edit the highlighted characters in a text in canvas using fabric.js, like change its color, font, style etc.

just like this http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html

to @user43250937
hey uhm. I tried it and it works! :D thanks.
I tried Underline, Bold, Italic, but I have a problem changing the color of the text, I tried :

```
// "cinput" is the id of the color picker.


addHandler('cinput', function(obj) {
    var color =  $("#cinput").val();

    var isColor = (getStyle(obj, 'fill') || '').indexOf(color) > -1;

     setStyle(obj, 'fill', isColor ? '' : color);

});
```

Comment: Why setStyle with `fontWeight`? for the text color is `fill` while for the background color use `textBackgroundColor`.

Comment: @user43250937 EDITED* wrong paste sorry. When I run the code, the text is gone.

Comment: You don't need the isColor line (that was to understand if it had underline or not, it's sort of a boolean value, as bold,italics,etc...), simply use `setStyle(obj, 'fill', color);`

Comment: @user43250937 thanks man. It worked! but I have a problem when I click the color picker, the text color will not change, It will only change after I clicked the color picker again , what I did was I added a handler with "onchange" instead of "onclick".

`function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onchange'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}`

Comment: Only one problem for each question :D

Comment: yes. I was about to say thanks earlier but I cant post codes in here. lol

Comment: No problem, i recommend to open a new question, so that other people can help as well.

Comment: okay :D I'm new here btw. thanks again!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually answers without a description of what you tried and what didn't work are completely ignored here, i'm answering this time because the fabricjs library is quite complex and the documentation is a bit lacking sometimes...

That page has samples for the [IText object](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html), text that can be edited in place (the content of the basic fabricjs text object can be modified only from outside via javascript).

Building a static IText object with different styles applied it's simple:

*HTML:*

```
<canvas id="canv" width="250" height="300" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); width: 400px; height: 400px; -webkit-user-select: none;"></canvas>
```

*Javascript:*

```
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canv');

var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: '#333',
  lineHeight: 1.1,
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: 80 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
      4: { fontSize: 20 }
    }
  }
});

canvas.add(iTextSample);
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLy9eqj6/)

As you can see you just specify the style for every character of each for each line (first for the `hello` line, then for the `world` line).

If you want something dynamic with the ability to select some text and change the appearance/style **there is some work to do**, you'll need to:

1. Add a button or a clickable element for each style (bold,italic,change color, change background,etc...) that you want to apply dynamically;
2. Add a click listener to each button with some code that changes the style of the selected text inside the IText.

You'll need a basic function that add handlers that you will reuse for every style button:

```
function addHandler(id, fn, eventName) {
  document.getElementById(id)[eventName || 'onclick'] = function() {
    var el = this;
    if (obj = canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      fn.call(el, obj);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }
  };
}
```

And some helper functions to change the styles:

```
function setStyle(object, styleName, value) {
  if (object.setSelectionStyles && object.isEditing) {
    var style = { };
    style[styleName] = value;
    object.setSelectionStyles(style);
  }
  else {
    object[styleName] = value;
  }
}

function getStyle(object, styleName) {
  return (object.getSelectionStyles && object.isEditing)
    ? object.getSelectionStyles()[styleName]
    : object[styleName];
}


addHandler('underline', function(obj) {
  var isUnderline = (getStyle(obj, 'textDecoration') || '').indexOf('underline') > -1;
  setStyle(obj, 'textDecoration', isUnderline ? '' : 'underline');
});
```

[Link to working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nzygs8a/) with a working underline button.

A bit of coding is involved as you can see, but it's not that complex, for the full list of available style options you can check the fabricjs documentation.

Comment: `object[styleName] = value;` in `setStyle` function, did not work but `object.set(styleName, value)` worked.
But Thank you very much.

Comment: In fabricjs version 2 you have to use `getStyleAtPosition(object.selectionStart)` instead of `getSelectionStyles()` in the `getStyle()` function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995602/how-do-i-get-itext-styles-in-fabric-js-ver-2/

Comment: your JSFiddle code does not work if I use with Fabric version 2.3.3. Even the comment from @Flemming cannot make it work.

Comment: @Istiaque i have just updated my project to work with ver. 2.3.3 and it still works. I used the cdnjs library: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.3/fabric.min.js