# Fabric.js IText - how to set a style for next letter?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Following uraimo's [great response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934252/how-to-edit-a-fabricjs-itext-and-apply-new-styles-e-g-highlighting-etc) I have managed to create a handler for making the text **bold**:

```
addHandler('bold', function (obj) {
  var isBold = getStyle(obj, 'fontWeight') === 'bold';
  setStyle(obj, 'textDecoration', isUnderline ? '' : 'underline');
});
```

It is attached to the button and it works fine whenever there is a portion of the text selected.

However, I need to also react on the button clicks when there is no text selected. Clicking a button in such case would result in bold text that is subsequently typed (just like hitting the "bold button" works in any text editor).

How can I do that?

Comment: I dropped the "itext" tag because on this site it means something totally different and I think it would only confuse things

Comment: @ChrisHaas Haas maybe the "fabric" tag should be removed too while you are at it. It doesn't feel like python here :D

Answer (score 0):

You can bold text that is subsequently typed and also the one applied by setting the preperty of text

```
addHandler('bold', function (obj) {
  var isBold = getStyle(obj, 'fontWeight') === 'bold';
  var style = {};
  style['fontwieight'] = isBold;
  object.setSelectionStyles(style);
  object.set('fontweight', isBold);
});
```