# How to style part of my drawn fabricjs text object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fabricjs

I have some code that allows me to toggle between text objects. I'd like to have the text objects include some styling, like Bold, Italic, etc for titles and such. text, however, am not sure how to accomplish this. Here's my current code:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 canvas.setHeight(300);
 canvas.setWidth(500);
  
 function textOne() {
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Regular Font', {
     left: 50,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50
   }));
 }
 
  function textTwo() {
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Bold Font', {
     left: 50,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial',
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50
   }));
 }
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="textOne()">One</button>
<button onclick="textTwo()">Two</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a FabricJS IText and apply new styles (e.g. highlighting, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934252/how-to-edit-a-fabricjs-itext-and-apply-new-styles-e-g-highlighting-etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `styles` property to style individual characters

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.IText.html#styles

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
 canvas.setHeight(300);
 canvas.setWidth(500);
  
 function textOne() {
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Regular Font', {
     left: 50,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50,
     styles:{
     0:{
      0:{fontWeight: 'bold'},
      1:{fontWeight: 'bold'}
     }
     }
   }));
 }
 
  function textTwo() {
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Bold Font', {
     left: 50,
     top: 100,
     fontFamily: 'arial',
     fontWeight: 'bold',
     fill: '#333',
     fontSize: 50,
     styles:{
     0:{
      0:{fontSize: 40},
      1:{fontSize: 30}
     }
     }
   }));
 }
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="textOne()">One</button>
<button onclick="textTwo()">Two</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect. [Do you know why this might not be working](https://jsfiddle.net/4nzygs8a/) with fabricjs 1.7.2 but DOES work with 1.5? Thank you.

Comment: Scratch that. It's working... and I don't know why haha. Eesh! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to also update the styles dynamically, you can use `setSelectionStyles` method like this:

```js
const text = new fabric.TextBox('Regular Font', {
  left: 50,
  top: 100,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50,
});
const start = 0
const end = 5
text.setSelectionStyles({fontWeight: 'bold'}, start, end);
```