# How to change the text formatting for only one segment of text?

Tags: fabricjs

I've seen on the fabricjs main page (fabricjs.com) this text among the examples.
They've inserted formatting for only one  word in the text:

[image]

And they have inserted picture into the text.

[image]

How can we do it?
Is it IText or Textbox or LabeledRect?

What will be the source text look like?
Will we use some kind of tags to markup the part of the text which must be formatted?

Haven't found anything about this in the tutorial.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29934252/5045563) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi on the docs you can see that `setSelectionStyles` exists.

Use it like this:

```js
myTextObject.setSelectionStyles({ underline: true, }, 3 ,7);
```

to set the underline property for chars 3,4,5,6,7

The hearth is an emoji, insert the unicode codepoint and it will just render

Comment: Thanks a lot! And is it possible to insert a link into IText? I mean to do some segment of the IText a clickable link. That also means that we distinguish between events - clicking the whole text vs. clicking the link.